# Safari background-image black lines

Tags: html, safari, background-image

Safari 7.0, I don't know why, but I see black lines on my background image

[image]

When I resize, browser window, the vertical one disappear
Does anyone know what is it?

website [fedoriv.com](http://www.fedoriv.com) (only Russian, sorry)
[image]

Comment: I have this too. I believe it's a bug in Webkit. I used to get it only when using border-radius but now in Safari 7 I'm getting it regardless for images that cover (via css background property) an element that spans the full width of the screen. Haven't tested other cases yet. Doesn't appear in any other webkit browsers as far as I can tell. Really annoys me that this is still a bug with Safari. I might try downloading one of the webkit nightly builds but then that doesn't solve the problem for anyone else viewing the website!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's rendering bug.. Not caused by code, but by the browser.. 
But I see, you use viewport, so it can be problem with margins in viewport units, or something like that, try to specificate your code here, like css and html around problem areas.. 
Looks like there is a problem with div, which is positioned above the photo