# Safari, thin lines when scaling image with css

Tags: html, css, safari

I am scaling two images(jpg) with the following css.

```
.social_img{
    height:20px;
}
```

It works well but in safari browsers (mac computer, ipad) I get a thin black line bottom and right, see image. Why does this happen and is there a way to remove this?

[image showing the thin lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbW6z.png)

Comment: The easiest way to figure this out is to inspect the element and see what css is already applied to it. If you're not applying anything, it's definitely a possibility it could be lines on the actual images themselves. It'd be useful if you posted some sort of example besides an image!

Comment: OK some more info, when I don't scale the image there is no black line. When I scale it there is one. There is no additional css and this only happens in Safari. To my knowledge the image has no borders of any kind. Here is a pure example http://labedzki.se/tests/black_line_test.html

Comment: Looks like this might be a bug. Here's another unsolved case with different images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677718/safari-background-image-black-lines

Comment: Thanks for investigating, hope there is someone out there that can figure this one out. I will file this as a bug with the webkit project. I'll just have to crop the images in the exact right size then I guess.